# Investment Brokering on an F-1 OPT?

Tags: employment, f1-visa

I am F-1 US Visa-holding student with an anticipated OPT authorization that is good May 9th through August 15th.

I have an opportunity to broker an investment in a manufacturing company registered in Nevada, USA. Am I eligible to claim brokerage on such an effort?  Or does my F-1 visa prevent me from collecting such compensation?

Comment: Seems like you aren't getting an answer here. Have you tried http://travel.stackexchange.com or http://expatriates.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. OPT work should be related to your field of study and the school/USCIS should be notified. Ask your school's DSO for more info. They should have informed you about these rules during orientation.

Also note that some broker work requires a specific brokers license.